# python urlib2 https authentication

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to query the API of a cluster via https with http authentication

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import urllib2
import base64

def proc():
    request = urllib2.Request("https://192.168.174.163:9443/restapi/server/api/v2/cluster")
    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ("admin", "admin")).replace('\n', '')
    request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
    result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    print result



def main():
    proc()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
/usr/bin/python /home/kshk/PycharmProjects/intelIDH/autoIDH.py
<addinfourl at 3074601484L whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0xb740e3ec>>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any idea why I am getting garbage values?

the same from command line works fine...

```
curl -k -u admin:admin -g https://10.0.20.101:9443/restapi/server/api/v2/cluster
```

and gives output

```
{"dnsresolution":true,"name":"clusterX","acceptlicense":true}
```

and i need to replicate this in python... any ideas...

Comment: What do you mean by "garbage values?" Exit code 0 means all went well, and the `<addinfourl>` object, well that's what you print on the last line of that function - what did you expect to happen?

Comment: In other words: Don't just `print result`, look at `result.code` for the HTTP status code, do `result.read()` to get the body of the HTTP response, etc...

Comment: i have pasted the expected output in the post

Comment: thanks makes sense, i got the ouput using result.read()

Comment: Now i need to open another url maintaining the previous auth session...any idea how to do it?

Comment: That's a different question. I suggest to use the [`requests`](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module and send back any session [cookies](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/?highlight=cookies#cookies) to the server.